# Search for file using Box.com Android SDK

Tags: search, box-api

Using the sdk, how do I search a file and get information about it? The only option I see is to go through all files and folders which is inconvenient and takes a lot of code.

Is there an easier way? If not with the SDK, a REST option perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this from http://developers.box.com/docs/#search

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/search?query=football&limit=1&offset=0 \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

I can search for any object and it returns a json response with the results.

I still don't know how to do it with the SDK but REST did the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Android sdk provides such an option.
You can do this:
boxClient.getSearchManager().search(searchQuery, null);
this method will return you a BoxCollection, every item in the collection should match your search query.